# Pivot_table returns all NAN

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have a df that has 4 categorical columns and 2 numerical columns.

| ID | Condition 1 | Condition 2 | Condition 3 | Condition 4 | Var 1 | Var 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | one | foo | 100 | 12 |
| 1 | B | X | two | bar | 90 | 13 |
| 1 | A | Y | two | bar | 80 | 14 |
| 2 | B | Y | one | foo | 20 | 156 |
| 2 | A | X | two | foo | 1 | 333 |
| 2 | B | Y | one | bar | 0 | 235 |

I would like to pivot it so that each user would have one row, with columns for each combination of the condition, once for with Var 1 and once with Var 2 values.

I tried running the following line

`table = pd.pivot_table(Purchases, index='ID', columns=['Condition 1', 'Condition 2','Condition 3', 'Condition 4'], values = ['Var1', 'Var2'],aggfunc = 'sum')`

But the output was full with NaN. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: runs well on the sample data, sans the typo `Var1` vs. `Var 1`. Also you can consider passing `fill_value=0` to `pivot_table`.

Comment: Var1 is just a generic name, that's not the names of my columns.